# Angular2 not getting to MVC WebAPI Get Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Angular2 with MVC 6 and I'm trying to make a call to a method on the MVC controller to return data.

My Angular service is as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import { ICountry } from '../interfaces/country';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class RecruiterService {
private _countriesUrl = 'Recruiter/Home/Countries';

constructor(private http: Http) { }

public getCountries = (): Observable<ICountry[]> =>  {
    return this.http.get(this._countriesUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <ICountry[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

//public getCountries = (): Observable<{}> => {
//    return this.http.get(this._countriesUrl)
//        .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
//        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
//        .catch(this.handleError);
//}
 private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
}
```

My ICountry interface is declared:

```
export interface ICountry {
CountryId: number;
CountryName: string;
ISOCode: number;
}
```

My MVC Controller is as follows:

```
[Area("Recruiter")]
[Route("Recruiter")]
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie")]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public class HomeController : LogControllerBase<HomeController>
{ .......
   [HttpGet("/Home/Countries")]
    public IActionResult GetCountries()
    {
        try
        {
            //return new JsonResult(new object[] { 1, "England", 3 });
            return Ok(_recruiterService.GetAllCountries());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Error occured in Recruiter Home/GetCountries: {ex}");
            return BadRequest("Obtaining Countries");
        }

    }......
```

At the point of calling the countriesUrl in my Angular service, I always receive the following error, I also get the same error when I swap out to the commented code in both the angular and mvc method. I never reach my breakpoint in the MVC controller method. I've also attempted to set the _countriesURL to be fully qualified e.g. starting http, but I still receive the same error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.Body.json (http.umd.js:777)
at MapSubscriber.http.get.map [as project] (recruiter.service.ts:20)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:75)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.umd.js:1180)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:3971)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:397)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:460)
```

In the Browser (Chrome) if I go to the network tab, I can see the call being made to the method even though it doesn't seem to breakpoint. In the headers for the call I get:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:42413/Recruiter/Home/Countries
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:42413
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Below are network header and preview tabs
[image: Header tab]
[image: Preview tab]

Comment: open the browser develop tools(F12), check what the server has returned

Comment: @aspark The error shown above is the error given by the browser (chrome). From the angular line `console.error(error);`

Comment: the error indicates that the returned content cound not parsed by angular(it's invalid json string), so we need check the server returns, it may be a 404, or 500 server error...

Comment: @aspark hmm strange. I'll update the question wit what I see in the headers for the call on the network tab in chrome

Comment: but you have not show the response body, or you can confirm the response is valid json, i guess the response is html which need authorise

Comment: @aspark looking in the Response tab seems to show the whole page as opposed to just the data that should be returned from the method

Comment: Wouldn't `Area` AND Route give you the route of `Recruiter\Recruiter\Home\Countries`?

Comment: @zaitsman you'd have thought so, but no If I leave one or the other out then depending on the way I choose to call a method, the call fails. Using both and all calls so far in the controller are fine. This is the first method where I'm trying to use Angular as opposed to 'Traditional MVC'. I don't think these have any baring on my problem

Comment: If this is the first time you are using these versions of these technologies together, I'd suggest starting with a much simpler example. Once you have a simple example working , then start adding all of the complexity.

Comment: Another option is to start with the `dotnet new angular` experience. I believe that it creates a first cut of an API and then either build from there or compare your code to the code it creates. For more information: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/dotnetNewAngularAndDotnetNewReact.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your web api has exception when initialize Controller.

Run debugger and check all `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` in [Exception Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) to see any others exception throw.

Comment: No, I don't believe I do. On my controller I have a constructor and I have an initial HttpGet Method that returns a base view and breakpoints in both of these get hit and the base view gets returned.